# Tidymodels Package: Visualising Bagged Trees using ggplot() to show the most important predictors

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, decision-tree, tidymodels

**Overview:**

I am following a tutorial (see below) to find the best fit models from bagged trees, random forests, boosted trees and general linear models.

**Tutorial (see examples below)**

https://bcullen.rbind.io/post/2020-06-02-tidymodels-decision-tree-learning-in-r/

**Issue**

In this case, I would like to explore the data further and visualise the most important predictors (see diagram below) for my data.

My data frame is called **FID** and the predictors in the bagged tree model involve:

1. Year (numeric)
2. Month (Factor)
3. Days (numeric)

The dependent variable is **Frequency (numeric)**

When I try to run the plot to visualise the most important predictor, I keep on getting this error message:-

**Error Message**

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `.extracts` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: rlang:::signal_abort(x)
```

If anyone has any advice on how to fix the error message, I would be deeply appreciative.

Many thanks in advance

**Examples of how to produce the plot from the R-code in the tutorial**

[image]
[image]

**Visualise the model**

[image]

**Plot to show the most important predictors**

[image]

**My R-code**

```
###########################################################
#split this single dataset into two: a training set and a testing set
data_split <- initial_split(FID)
# Create data frames for the two sets:
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)

 # resample the data with 10-fold cross-validation (10-fold by default)
  cv <- vfold_cv(train_data)
###########################################################

##Produce the recipe

rec <- recipe(Frequency_Blue ~ ., data = FID) %>% 
          step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
          step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
          step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
          step_dummy(all_nominal(), -has_role("id vars")) # dummy codes categorical variables

###################################################################################

#####Fit the Bagged Tree Model
mod_bag <- bag_tree() %>%
            set_mode("regression") %>%
             set_engine("rpart", times = 10) #10 bootstrap resamples
                

##Create workflow
wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
                   add_recipe(rec) %>%
                       add_model(mod_bag)

##Fit the model
plan(multisession)

fit_bag <- fit_resamples(
                      wflow_bag,
                      cv,
                      metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
                      control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
                      )

##########################################################
##Visualise the model

##Open a plotting window
dev.new()

# extract roots
bag_roots <-  function(x){
                      x %>% 
                      dplyr::select(.extracts) %>% 
                      unnest(cols = c(.extracts)) %>% 
                      dplyr::mutate(models = map(.extracts,
                      ~.x$FID)) %>% 
                      dplyr::select(-.extracts) %>% 
                      unnest(cols = c(fit_bag)) %>% 
                      mutate(root = map_chr(fit_bag,
                      ~as.character(.x$fit$frame[1, 1]))) %>%
                      dplyr::select(root)  
              }


# plot the bagged tree model
  bag_roots(fit_bag) %>% 
          ggplot(mapping = aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(root)))) + 
          geom_bar() + 
          coord_flip() + 
          labs(x = "root", y = "count")

 #Error Message

  Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
  x Column `.extracts` doesn't exist.
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
  Called from: rlang:::signal_abort(x)
```

**Data frame - FID**

```
  structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December"), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(36, 
28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
43, 38), Days = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to adjust here:

- Be sure to `extract` what you need during `fit_resamples()`
- Use the correct variable names for **your** data that you are creating in the `bag_roots()` function.

It will end up like this:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(baguette)

FID <- structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                               2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
                               2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                               2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), 
                      Month = structure(c(1L, 
                                          2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                          5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                          8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
                                                                             "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                                                                             "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
                      Frequency = c(36, 
                                    28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
                                    7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
                                    43, 38), Days = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
                                                      29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
                                                      28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                -36L), 
                 class = "data.frame")

data_split <- initial_split(FID)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)
cv <- vfold_cv(train_data, v = 3)

rec <- recipe(Frequency ~ ., data = FID) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
  step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
  step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) # dummy codes categorical variables


mod_bag <- bag_tree() %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("rpart", times = 10) #10 bootstrap resamples


wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod_bag)

fit_bag <- fit_resamples(
  wflow_bag,
  cv,
  metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE,
                              extract = function(x) extract_model(x))
)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int,
#>     flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along, modify, prepend,
#>     splice
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vctrs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     data_frame
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     data_frame
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rpart'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dials':
#> 
#>     prune

bag_roots <-  function(x){
  x %>% 
    dplyr::select(.extracts) %>% 
    unnest(cols = c(.extracts)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(models = map(.extracts,
                               ~.x$model_df)) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-.extracts) %>% 
    unnest(cols = c(models)) %>% 
    mutate(root = map_chr(model,
                          ~as.character(.x$fit$frame[1, 1]))) %>%
    dplyr::select(root)  
}


# plot the bagged tree model
library(forcats)
bag_roots(fit_bag) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(root)))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(x = "root", y = "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Not super exciting, but hopefully your real, larger dataset shows more interesting results!